# Windows Nokia Lumia 930 suddenly saying full

Tags: nokia-lumia-930

I can't access "other" folder on lumia 930 phone which shows as 20 gb full!  Anyone got any ideas?  I can't see it at all on a pc when connecting

Comment: Are you talking about others present in Storage sense?

Comment: Is is on SD card or on internal phone's memory?

Comment: When you go to storage sense in the menu in settings, it shows the whole thing as full.  I think it's the phone.  And it's quite sudden.  Apps and games 1.12 gb music 0 videos 1.31 gb podcasts 0 photos 2.33 gb email +messaging 13.71mb documents 1.00 mb maps 505.27 mb system 3.38 gb temporary files 0 other 20.48 gb!!.  When I tap on this "other" it suggests connecting to pc.  The pc doesn't see this folder

Answer (score 1):

A very common problem to most windows phones after large updates!

There are two ways to fix this: Easy one first -
Just pack up all your stuff and send them to OneDrive. Not just using backup and restore section of your settings, but manually too. Then in settings hit 'reset phone' in about section. Plug in your phone while you do some other stuff. Finally after the gears are gone, you get your phone free of those 20GB of junk.

There's another risky way without resetting your phone. (but that's really very risky!) Comment if you want to know. Hope this answer helped you. If it did, give me an upvote!